# Area covered by Brownian motion of 2D disc

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, brownian-motion

I would like to know the expected value for the area covered by a disc of radius $R$ whose center undergoes Brownian motion (diffusion).

Specifically, let $\mathbf{X}_t$ represent a two-dimensional Brownian motion, and define the covered set $C_t = \bigcup_t B(\mathbf{X}_t,R)$ to be the union of discs centered at every point along the realized trajectory.  Define $A_t$ to be the area of the set $C_t$.  What is the expected value $\mathbb{E}[A_t]$ as a function of $t$?

I am specifically interested in this for the mathematical modeling of a chemical reaction and would be happy with an approximate solution that works in the short-to-moderate time regime, where $|x_t|$ is at most (say) $5R$.  I think that this time regime is too short to use the lattice random walk result for the number of distinct sites ($t / \log t$ from Dvoretzky and Erdös).

Thank you.

Comment: There is a recent paper of Peres and Sousi on a related topic, showing that if a shape with area $A$ has its centre moved by a BM, then the shape that minimizes the total area covered is the disc.

Comment: That is interesting to know, as the process I am modeling involves cells that are not spherical (but I am happy with a "spherical cow" approximation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u(r,t)$ solve the heat equation in polar coordinates in the complement of the disk:
$$ \partial_t u(r,t)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{r}\partial_r r \partial_r u(r,t), \quad r>1$$
with initial condition $u(r,0)=0$ and boundary condition $u(1,t)=1$.  I claim that the number you seek is 
$$ A_t = \pi + 2\pi\int_1^\infty u(r,t)r dr.$$
(This is because $u(r,t)$ gives the probability that a Brownian particle released at radius $r$ has hit the disk by time $t$. The first term $\pi$ is just the area of the disk at time $0$. I have transferred the problem to one in which your particle remains fixed and potential target points move.)

There is an exact expression for $u$ (see [Wendel, J. G. "Hitting spheres with Brownian motion". Ann. Prob. 8, 164 (1980).](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aop/1176994833), which I learned of from the answer to this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96703/finite-time-hitting-probabilities-for-brownian-motion-in-the-plane), but ultimately traced back to a [paper of Carslaw and Jaeger](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-46/1/361.full.pdf) from 1940).  It is most easily expressed in terms of the Laplace transform $F(r,\lambda)=\int_0^\infty u(r,t) e^{-\lambda t}$:
$$F(r,\lambda) = \frac{K_0(\sqrt{2\lambda}r)}{\lambda K_0(\sqrt{2\lambda})}, \quad r\ge 1,$$
where $K_0$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind and order $0$. In your case the integral over $r$ can be done exactly since $\int r K_0(r) dr = - K_1(r)$. So 
$$ \int_0^\infty A_t e^{-\lambda t} d t \ = \ \frac{\pi}{\lambda} + \frac{2\pi K_1(\sqrt{2\lambda})}{\lambda (2\lambda)^{\frac{3}{2}}K_0(\sqrt{2\lambda})}.$$
You can recover $A_t$ by analytic continuation of the right hand side to complex $\lambda$ and Fourier inversion.

Comment: It will take me more time to digest the solution, but I believe that transferring the problem to an absorbing disk at the origin is valid.  Thank you.

Comment: I should add that the contour integral you get for $A_t$ can be transformed into a form suitable for numerical integration.  I wanted to compute $u(r,t)$ for various values of $r$ and $t$ a couple of years ago; I was able to do so easily in Matlab using off the shelf numerical integrators.

Answer (score 4):

Your process $C_t$ is better known by the amusing name of [Wiener sausage](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Wiener_sausage), and its expected area $E[A_t]$ has been extensively studied (though more so for long times than short).

I found a 2010 paper by Yuji Hamana which gives small-time asymptotics for the area of the $d$-dimensional Wiener sausage; for $d=2$ it looks like we have, as $t \to 0$,
$$E[A_t] \sim \pi R^2 + \sqrt{8 \pi t} R + o(\sqrt{t}).$$
There's also a 2013 paper by Kôhei Uchiyama that obtains a similar result.

> [MR2761916](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2761916) Hamana, Yuji. 
>   On the expected volume of the Wiener sausage.
>   J. Math. Soc. Japan 62 (2010), no. 4, 1113–1136. [Open access at Project Euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1288703099).
>
> [MR2988115](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2988115) Uchiyama, Kôhei. The expected area of the Wiener sausage swept by a disc. Stochastic Process. Appl. 123 (2013), no. 1, 191–211.

Comment: Thank you for the references.  Unfortunately, I think I will have to use the inverse Laplace transform of the formula given above as I am in the regime where $\sqrt{t}$ is comparable to $R$.